# matplotlib: grid in 3D plots

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib, grid, plot

In `matplotlib`, how can I show a grid in 3D scatter plot?

In 2D plots I just do: `plt.grid(True)` and it works like a charm. Now with 3D plots the same call returns a warning:

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2792, in grid
   ret = gca().grid(b, which, axis, **kwargs)    
TypeError: grid() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the grid method of the axes to turn the grid on and off.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, projection='3d')
ax.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[7,4,6,2,8],[4,6,8,9,2],'*')
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_title('grid on')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, projection='3d')
ax2.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[7,4,6,2,8],[4,6,8,9,2],'*')
ax2.grid(False)
ax2.set_title('grid off')
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d plot with and without grid]

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Then I guess it's turned on by default. It turns out to be not as useful as it might have been, in a 3D plot, to identify correctly the three coordinates. Do you know of any other method that makes the three coordinates of each plotted point clear?

Comment: I guess you could label each point, or key points.  Otherwise no.

Comment: @RickyRobinson You could try generating stereoscopic pairs