# Matplotlib: Grid over the surface of a 3D plot with three (1D) arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, grid, surface

I have 3(1D) arrays so to  plot a surface as far as I know the only thing I can use is TRISURF. But I don´t know how to put a grid over the surface,[like this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3ttb.png)

This is the part of my code I´m having problem with:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('jet',256), linewidth=0.5, antialiased=True)
```

Thanks, a lot.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279978/matplotlib-grid-in-3d-plots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib: GRID and COLORMAP with TRISURF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63832711/matplotlib-grid-and-colormap-with-trisurf)